# Matching Price Filter Values in an array and get the price value in between two given price slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I've two arrays one array is the value of price slider in which their are two values one is starting value and other is ending value of slider, i want to check what price what value are coming in between from the slider start and end value, please check screenshot

[image]

Code for slider which is starting and ending value

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    values: [ 1, 50 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).text( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + "-$" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      collection.filterPrice(event, ui, getPriceTags());
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).text( "$1" + "-$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Out out of slider

[image]

results i want are

```
if slider value is from 10 to 50 so this checks the into the array
if any of the value is in between these 10 to 50 so it gives the result 20 50
or
if slider value is 10 to 60 so the results should be 20 50 and 50 to 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I hope this finally gets to the point...)

This code returns all price segments whose range overlaps (either entirely or just partially) with the price range selected with the slider.

```js
/*
 * NOTES: price segments should not overlap
 */

const priceSegments = ['20-50', '51-100']; // originally was ['20-50', '50-100'] see note
const sliderRange = [1, 50];
const pricesList = [{
    value: 30.5,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    value: 27.7,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    value: 50.0,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    value: 55.5,
    count: 2
  }
];

// if you want an array of strings (e.g. ["20-50", "51-100"])
const priceSegmentsMatchingRange_arrayOfStrings = priceSegments.filter(segment => {
  const [segmentMin, segmentMax] = segment.split('-');
  const [rangeMin, rangeMax] = sliderRange;
  return (
    (parseInt(segmentMin) < parseInt(rangeMin) && parseInt(segmentMax) >= parseInt(rangeMin)) ||
    (parseInt(segmentMin) >= parseInt(rangeMin) && parseInt(segmentMax) <= parseInt(rangeMax)) ||
    (parseInt(segmentMin) <= parseInt(rangeMax) && parseInt(segmentMax) > parseInt(rangeMax))
  );
});
console.log(priceSegmentsMatchingRange_arrayOfStrings);

// if you want an array of arrays of strings (e.g. [["20", "50"], ["51", "100"]])
const priceSegmentsMatchingRange_arrayArraysOfStrings = priceSegments.filter(segment => {
  const [segmentMin, segmentMax] = segment.split('-');
  const [rangeMin, rangeMax] = sliderRange;
  return (
    (parseInt(segmentMin) < parseInt(rangeMin) && parseInt(segmentMax) >= parseInt(rangeMin)) ||
    (parseInt(segmentMin) >= parseInt(rangeMin) && parseInt(segmentMax) <= parseInt(rangeMax)) ||
    (parseInt(segmentMin) <= parseInt(rangeMax) && parseInt(segmentMax) > parseInt(rangeMax))
  );
}).map(segment => segment.split('-'));
console.log(priceSegmentsMatchingRange_arrayArraysOfStrings);

// if you want an array of arrays of numbers (e.g. [[20, 50], [51, 100]])
const priceSegmentsMatchingRange_arrayArraysOfNumbers = priceSegments.filter(segment => {
  const [segmentMin, segmentMax] = segment.split('-');
  const [rangeMin, rangeMax] = sliderRange;
  return (
    (parseInt(segmentMin) < parseInt(rangeMin) && parseInt(segmentMax) >= parseInt(rangeMin)) ||
    (parseInt(segmentMin) >= parseInt(rangeMin) && parseInt(segmentMax) <= parseInt(rangeMax)) ||
    (parseInt(segmentMin) <= parseInt(rangeMax) && parseInt(segmentMax) > parseInt(rangeMax))
  );
}).map(segment => segment.split('-').map(item => parseInt(item)));
console.log(priceSegmentsMatchingRange_arrayArraysOfNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/filter)

For example:

```js
allValues = [
  { val: 5, count: 2}, 
  { val: 6, count: 2}, 
  { val: 7, count: 2}, 
  { val: 8, count: 2}, 
  { val: 9, count: 2}, 
  { val: 10, count: 3}
];
  
var sliderStartVal = 6;
var sliderEndVal = 9;
  
console.log(allValues.filter(x => x.val > sliderStartVal && x.val < sliderEndVal));

// Gives [{"val":7,"count":2},{"val":8,"count":2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you simply need to use `Array.prototype.filter()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

[EDIT]
I am still not 100% sure I got what you want to achieve but, as far as I could understand, this edited snippet might be what you need.

```js
/*
 * NOTES:
 * I think there are a couple of logical error I eliminated in this code snippet
 *   1. price segments should not overlap
 *   2. it should not be possible to select a price lower/higher than the lowes/highest price segment
 */

const priceSegments = ['20-50', '51-100']; // originally was ['20-50', '50-100'] see note (1.)
const sliderRange = [20, 50]; // originally was [1, 50] - see note (2.)
const pricesList = [{
    value: 30.5,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    value: 27.7,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    value: 50.0,
    count: 2
  },
  {
    value: 55.5,
    count: 2
  }
];

const priceRange = priceSegments.reduce((outObj, segment) => {
  /*
   * if the slider minimum falls within the segment,
   * set the minPrice to the segment minumum
   */
  if (
    parseInt(segment.split('-')[0]) <= parseInt(sliderRange[0]) &&
    parseInt(segment.split('-')[1]) >= parseInt(sliderRange[0])
  ) {
    outObj.minPrice = parseInt(segment.split('-')[0]);
  }

  /*
   * if the slider maximum falls within the segment,
   * set the maxPrice to the segment maximum
   */
  if (
    parseInt(segment.split('-')[0]) <= parseInt(sliderRange[1]) &&
    parseInt(segment.split('-')[1]) >= parseInt(sliderRange[1])
  ) {
    outObj.maxPrice = parseInt(segment.split('-')[1]);
  }
  return outObj;
}, {
  minPrice: 0,
  maxPrice: 0
});

const {
  minPrice,
  maxPrice
} = priceRange;
const pricesInRange = pricesList.filter((price) => price.value >= minPrice && price.value <= maxPrice);

console.log(pricesInRange);
```

Comment: most of it you got my point but their is one more array and need to match and get values from the other array.

Comment: @SalmanKhanSohoo, could you clarify which array I am missing, please? In the code snippet, two arrays are used as "input": `priceRange` (which is then destructure into the two constants `minPrice` and `maxPrice`) corresponds to your `ui.value` and `pricesList` is the list of prices of all the products. Finally, the list of prices falling within the range you select with the slider is put into a third array (`pricesInRange`).

Comment: Dear @secan please check screenshot for better understanding, hope it will clear you what actually i want to match and want the results
http://prntscr.com/ui2gf9

Comment: @SalmanKhanSohoo, ok _maybe_ now I got it. I updated the snippet in my answer; please have a look and check whether it actually does what you want.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy, but i don't want the prices, actually i want segment in the results, what segment is coming in between the slider Range. it can result more then one segment.

Comment: @SalmanKhanSohoo, ok, let's see if we can finally reach and understanding... ;) What you want is a list of all segments included within the "min" and "max" values selected with the slider, is it correct? In this case the solution is illustrated by the code which I am going to add into a new answer.